# create script in Cordova fails with unexpected error in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 12.10, I am trying to set up cordova 2.3.0(PhoneGap) based on the instructions present here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android.

but when I run the script I get the following error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: [ ! -e "$BUILD_PATH"/framework/libs/commons-codec-1.7.jar ]  
exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

I looked up the commons-codec-1.7.jar and it is present where it should be:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 259600 Jan 21 15:32 framework/libs/commons-codec-1.7.jar
```

I tried hard coding the path and I still get the same error.so why am I seeing this error.

Any ideas what could be wrong or missing here?

thanks ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this exact same problem, I'm not sure what solved it in the end but here's a list of what I did.

- Reinstalled the android sdk
- Installed ADT for eclipse (since I don't use eclipse I didn't install it initially)
- On the SDK manager I installed the extras and API's 14~17

I should have tried to run the command after each step to pinpoint the problem. If you find out exactly what solved it please tell.

Comment: The problem was the Android SDK, for some reason my SDK was not updated properly and re-instalaltion of SDK files did the trick.

Comment: I have the same issue, but sadly after doing all three of those it's still failing with the same error

Comment: See skrafi's answer - stop the script from throwing away potentially useful error messages by getting rid of the `&> /dev/null`. Turns out my problem was that I didn't have `ant` installed.

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely because Java and/or Apache Ant is not installed properly. I had the same issue until I installed the Oracle JDK and Ant with the following commands:

```sh
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
sudo apt-get install ant
```

Comment: Many thanks fiznool! After a weekend dealing with the same issue I came to this thread and your instruction saved my day.

Comment: ant was missing for me as well. On gentoo you'll want to `emerge -av ant-core` as emerging `ant` brings in a ridiculous number of dependencies

Answer (score 6):

I recommend to make `create` script output more verbose to research build problems. So you can edit this line:

```
(cd "$BUILD_PATH"/framework && ant jar &> /dev/null )
```

to

```
(cd "$BUILD_PATH"/framework && ant jar )
```

This helps me to determine my problem:

```
makk@localhost:~/projects/eclipse/cordova-android/bin$ ./create ~/projects/eclipse/plackarta com.MyApp MyApp
Buildfile: build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/makk/projects/eclipse/cordova-android/framework/build.xml:33: The required minimum version of ant is 1.8.0, you have Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on September 8 2010

Total time: 0 seconds
```

You can fix this depending on your OS. On modern systems you'll probably get luck following fiznool answer. Also you can try this solution (on your own risk!): https://askubuntu.com/questions/55488/install-upgrade-to-apache-ant-1-8-2. There are also ready-to-use binaries on http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi (helped me with my old 10.04 Ubuntu).

Comment: Excellent! doing this indicated that I did not in fact have "ant" installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue too. Installing Apache Ant fixed az fiznool suggested it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

After removing the `&> /dev/null`, I figured out what was really happening.

The `commons-codec-1.7.jar` script was returning the following error:

`Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.`

So I only had to add the variable `JAVA_HOME` in my `.bashrc` file, like this:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/`

Everything worked fine after that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in my case i used "sudo cordova platform add android" which worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Android 4.2 (API 17) and it solved errors

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
chown -R xxxx:xxxx  /path_to_cordova
```

it works for me!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, if you created the project with a space in the project name (even if you nicely placed the whole name between quotes), adding Android will fail. And a dash (-) causes the same problem.